# MS Sql Server 2005+ table indexes creation can be automated?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I was reading Ian Stirk's [Uncover Hidden Data to Optimize Application Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135978.aspx) article on MSDN Magazine, and now I am wondering if table indexes creation could be automated, as Google AppEngine does for its BigTable.

There is any tool or Sql Server feature that automates table index creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm glad you enjoyed my article!

In my new book about SQL Server performance via DMVs (www.manning.com/stirk), in chapter 10, you'll see a script that allows you to automatically created indexes... there's also a script to remove unused indexes... you can see how these could be used together.

Thanks
Ian

Answer (score 3):

No, as far as I know, there's no feature in SQL Server that enables automatic table index creation.

I wouldn't think it to be a good idea, either, because getting the right indexes in place will depend on a multitude of factors, hardly any of which can be really truly automated.

Sure - you can place a primary key on any column called "ID" - until you run into a case where you need a primary key on something else....

Sure, it makes sense to index foreign key columns in the child table - but sometimes, the added overhead for INSERTs can more than offset the gains of having the index.

Getting the right indices in place is just way too dependant on your actual usage and a lot of dynamic, usage parameters (and design decisions on your part, too) so I'd be surprised if any solution would really work all that well...

Marc

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any tools, and the best way to create indexes is to actually check the queries and their execution plans manually. I don't think that an automated tool will ever be as good as a few good DBA's analyzing the data together with the Profiler.

But, if you feel like giving a shot yourself, I recommend that you start looking at the performance views in the SQL Server.

Start with the function `sys.dm_db_missing_index_columns`, that should give you a hint of which columns that could benefit from being indexed.

`sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` could show you which indexes are useless, or could be optimized as well.

`sys.dm_exec_cached_plans`, `sys.dm_exec_query_plan`, `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` and `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` should show you queries performed and how they perform, and together with information from the other tables, you could probably find out which ones that need more work.

Actually, I vaguely recall some wizard that can help you to analyze performance in the Profiler, probably not automatically, but it might be possible to put that in a Maintenance plan.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread, but I thought someone may find this interesting:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/06/01/613516.aspx

Even though it sounds awesome I heed caution - indexes can cripple a system as much as they can make it fly - only use if you know what you are doing!

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.